# Systeme not working with more complicated inputs

Tags: system, equation

I was trying to accomplish something 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPcJF.png),
but TeX gives me an error in french, which says something about "a clue not being a full number" and I don't know what to do. No solutions in previous posts seemed to work. I can't paste all of 114 lines of my code here, so I'll just paste what I've tried:

```
  \begin{equation*}
  \systeme{m_2\left(v_{2p}^2-v_{2f}^2\right) = m_1v_{1f}^2, m_2\left(v_{2p}-v_{2f}\right) = m_1v_{1f}}
  \end{equation*}
```

I am using the `systeme` package.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. You might want to ask this question on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use \prime for *'* in latex equations

I modified the code as follows:

```
  $ m_1\left(v-v_{1}^\prime \right) = m_2v_{2}^\prime $
  $ m_1\left(v^2-v_{1}^\prime2 \right) = m_2v_{2}^\prime2 $
```

You can use begin equation and end equation as well:

```
\begin{equation}
  m_1\left(v-v_{1}^\prime \right) = m_2v_{2}^\prime
  m_1\left(v^2-v_{1}^{2}\prime \right) = m_2v_{2}^{2}\prime
\end{equation}
```